# VB.NET Variable is used before

Tags: vb.net

I have usual peace of code for VB.NET, such this:

```
    Dim ds = New DataSet
    Using mCon As NpgsqlConnection = dbUtil.getConnection()
        Using t As NpgsqlTransaction = mCon.BeginTransaction()

        ... some code ...

            t.Commit()
        End Using
    End Using
```

With this code I have in "mCon.BeginTransaction()" *mCon* underlined with green and warning message is "Variable 'mCon' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime".

Why is that and how to get rid of this?

Comment: it means that VS cant see that a valid instance exists for the connection. what does `dbUtil.getConnection()` return?

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks. I remove global imports from "Imported Namespaces" and now I place Imports in every file. When I placed Imports NpgSQL into dbUtil this warning dissappears. Sorry for asking too fast.

Comment: no problem ... it happens